# How many officers on board Type VII-C U-boat?

Tags: world-war-two, war, germany, naval, world

As the topic states I am curious of how many offiers were on board a type VII-C U-boat during WW2. I know the crew size was typically 42 to 48, but what was the breakdown of the crew?

Bonus points for explanation of each officer's duty.

Comment: Google search of ["*crew of type VII-C U-boat*"](http://www.uboataces.com/ref-crew.shtml) rapidly turns up a listing of key officers and petty officers on a U-Boat.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Perhaps, but that website isn't exactly a "standard reference source", and there's no sourcing info there that I can find. How reliable is it?

Comment: Don't have an answer, but go watch the movie Das Boot if you haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Grey Wolf: U-Boat Crewman of World War II](https://books.google.com/books?id=eJjvCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=type%20vii%20c%20u-boat%20officers&pg=PT76#v=onepage&q=officer&f=false), the officers of a typical crew consisted of...

- Commander - a Kapitänleutnant or Oberleutnant
- First Officer - Oberleutnant zur See or Leutnant zur See
- Second Officer - Leutnant zur See
- Engineering Officer - Leutnant or Oberleutnant zur See
- Third Watch Officer - Held by a warrant officer, typically the Obersteuermann (Navigator)
- Fourth Watch Officer - Non-commissioned held by the Oberbootsmaat (Bosun)

And there were various warrant and petty officers which made up the crew. A complete breakdown is in the book and available via Google Books.

So four commissioned officers for a crew of about 50.

Comment: Awesome answer and thank you for the link to the book! I will definitely be checking it out.

Comment: Any indication what the bare minimum of crew would be to operate it (skeleton crew)?

Comment: @Mast Buy the book and let us know! $11 on Kindle. :)